# Stack can't find Chart or Chart-cairo, though the cabal file calls for them

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I'm trying to use Haskell stack (lts-6.12 resolver) to set up and run a [small demo program](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart-1.8/docs/Graphics-Rendering-Chart-Easy.html) for Chart. I created the project with `stack new`, `stack init`, etc. then modified the generated `Main.hs`, adding the demo code. I also added the Chart and Chart-cairo packages to the .cabal file and ran `stack build`. Lots and lots of packages installed, including Chart and Chart-cairo, judging from the output, and when it was finally done, it tried to compile `Main.hs`, but failed with the following errors:

```
/home/asdf/my-project/app/Main.hs:4:8:
Could not find module ‘Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Easy’
It is a member of the hidden package ‘Chart-1.6@Chart_Cz416CvPROo70VikOoIoki’.
Perhaps you need to add ‘Chart’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

/home/asdf/my-project/app/Main.hs:5:8:
Could not find module ‘Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Backend.Cairo’
It is a member of the hidden package ‘Chart-cairo-1.6@Chart_I1HGJHEm7pvIiSoYgOrXbq’.
Perhaps you need to add ‘Chart-cairo’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

How can stack be loading these packages successfully, then be somehow unable to find them later? How can it have the nerve (jk) to ask me to put the dependencies in my .cabal file, when it has already obtained them from there to load them in the first place?

Here is the dependency list:

```
$ stack list-dependencies
Chart 1.6
Chart-cairo 1.6
StateVar 1.1.0.4
adjunctions 4.3
array 0.5.1.0
base 4.8.2.0
base-orphans 0.5.4
bifunctors 5.2
binary 0.7.5.0
bytestring 0.10.6.0
cairo 0.13.1.1
colour 2.3.3
comonad 4.2.7.2
containers 0.5.6.2
contravariant 1.4
data-default-class 0.0.1
deepseq 1.4.1.1
distributive 0.5.0.2
exceptions 0.8.3
filepath 1.4.0.0
free 4.12.4
ghc-prim 0.4.0.0
hashable 1.2.4.0
hmatrix 0.17.0.2
integer-gmp 1.0.0.0
kan-extensions 4.2.3
lens 4.13
machine-learning 0.1.0.0
mtl 2.2.1
old-locale 1.0.0.7
operational 0.2.3.3
parallel 3.2.1.0
prelude-extras 0.4.0.3
primitive 0.6.1.0
profunctors 5.2
random 1.1
reflection 2.1.2
semigroupoids 5.0.1
semigroups 0.18.1
split 0.2.3.1
stm 2.4.4.1
storable-complex 0.2.2
tagged 0.8.4
template-haskell 2.10.0.0
text 1.2.2.1
time 1.5.0.1
transformers 0.4.2.0
transformers-compat 0.4.0.4
unordered-containers 0.2.7.1
utf8-string 1.0.1.1
vector 0.11.0.0
void 0.7.1
```

Comment: Can you show your .cabal file?

Comment: Do you have an `executable` stanza or `library` stanza or both?

Comment: @ErikR I just figured this out after you requested the cabal file and I went to anonymize it, lol. It is indeed a confusion of stanzas. I didn't expect more than one so just added the dependencies to the first ``build-depends`` I saw. If you concoct some kind of answer to that effect I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have both an `executable` and `library` stanza, try listing
the dependencies in both.

If your executable depends on those dependencies but you've only listed
them in your library stanza you'll get that error - dependencies from
different stanzas are independent of each other.